# How to Allow notification permission for desktop-notifications in Chrome Browser using python scripting

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Hi i have been trying to automate a page using Selenium Python. And in one of the page it requires the user to grant permission for mic & cam. I have written the code for the same using the Chrom_Options() even then This dosn't help me in selecting the Allow permission automatically using the script.

[image]

Below is the code that I use and every time I need to manually click on the allow permission button

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from random import shuffle
from time import sleep
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
import math
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#To Enable the notification (Allow Microphone and Camera)
option = Options()

option.add_argument("--enable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--enable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
})

driver = Chrome(options=option, executable_path='/Users/downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://study.yupl.us/studies/5d5a64aa8b5bb92fb776753b?auth=false')

def GetVideoDuration(video_element):
    val = VideoFileClip(video_element)
    return val.duration

zip=[99524,90209]
shuffle(zip)

#click Start Study
sleep(5)
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='START STUDY']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    pass

#Enter the ZIP code
try:
    zipcode=driver.find_element_by_id('zipEntry_zipCode')
    zipcode.send_keys(zip[0])
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    pass

#After entering Continue Button Click on Continue to Proceed
try:
    continuebutton=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Continue"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", continuebutton)
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    pass

#Get The video duration and wait for the video to completly play
videoduration=0
try:
    sleep(10)
    questionvideo = driver.find_element_by_id('studyMediaVideo')
    video = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].getAttribute('src')", questionvideo)
    videoduration = GetVideoDuration(video)
    # Play the video
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", questionvideo)
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    pass


#wait till the video is completly played
sleep(math.ceil(videoduration))

#Click on Answer Question
try:
    answer=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="ANSWER"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", answer)
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following experimental options:

> "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic"
>   "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera"
>   "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation"
>   "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications"

Comment: Where do you add these?

Comment: On the Options object you created.