# python code for asking microphone permission in Chrome and other Browser?

Tags: python

I am developing an application where I need microphone access. So, anyone can tell me the python code for asking microphone permission in Chrome or any other Browser.[image]

Comment: addArguments('use-fake-device-for-media-stream')

Comment: May be same as-  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40706/how-to-allow-notification-permission-for-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-browser

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
options.add_argument('use-fake-device-for-media-stream')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Or else you can pass the chrome profile that has microphone enabled for your application

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=<profilepath>")
```

eg

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=c:\profile\user-data")
```

if the profile is not in user-data\default then you have to also add

```
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=<folder_name>')
```

Comment: I have a link and when I clicked on the link it will call a python function. And also on clicking the link, I want to get microphone access. So that I can get the speech audio and then I will convert to text (using speech recognizer) and do the further process. So, where I will place the code to do all this work?

Comment: @SubhadipMondal  Before you create chrome driver ! driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)